# Drupal cache queries run slowly

Tags: drupal-7

I have two Drupal sites, one on testing server and one on my localhost. These sites are same source and same database.

From query log of Devel module, site's loading speed on localhost is very slow, but on server is not. The problem is caused by cache, session, history queries...

Both of two environments are not using MemCache. The innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256MB (localhost) is greater than server.

Could you please tell me why the localhost is slower and how to config my localhost to be same testing server? Thanks.

[image: Above is locahost log, below is server log]

Comment: Issue seems occur on Windows. Linux has no this problem. I'm using UwAmp. I also tried to install Xampp, Wamp but not fixed yet. Could someone help me to fix this issue, please?

Comment: Using drupal app in My server is slow with high configurations and my local is fast...lol